# Android Jetpack Compose - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setContent(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception when trying to run `setContent{ Composable() }`.

Full code:

```
class ComposeFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
        ComposeView(requireContext()).apply { setContent { Text("hello") } }

}
```

Full exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setContent(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V in class Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView' appears in /data/app/~~3OmVKUoYitZ_S4H81xmyuw==/my.app.package-PAQxAKmtRuhnzp4M2DME8w==/base.apk)
```

Solutions/answers to similar questions suggest adding `buildFeatures { compose = true }` or `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion`, I have already done this but the issue persists.

My full compose Gradle config is as follows:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    useIR = true
}

buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

composeOptions{
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.5"
}

implementation( "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1" )
implementation( "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1" )
implementation( "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.5" )
implementation( "androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.0.5" )
implementation( "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.5" )
implementation( "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07" )
androidTestImplementation( "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.5" )
```

Comment: Please provide a sample project to reproduce the bug. I've tried creating a new project (Fragment + ViewModel), added your gradle configuration, replaced generated fragment code with yours and it runs fine.

Comment: Hi @PhilipDukhov , I will do so when I get the chance, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Ran into the same exception today, so I put my solution here in case someone else needs it.

In my case, it was because the setup below was missing from the `build.gradle` file, of the `android` section

```
    buildFeatures.compose = true
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = Versions.COMPOSE
    }
```

`Version.COMPOSE` is the compose version, in my case it was `1.1.0-alpha05`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was solved by adding the following lines to my app's build.gradle file:

```
android {
   buildFeatures {
       compose true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this lines to your module's gradle file :

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = rootProject.extra["compose_version"] as String
}
```

If you work on muli-module project, you have to add this for each compose included modules.

Answer (score 2):

Your Compose version is very old and is almost certainly the reason for your problems. Update your project gradle with the following. Make sure to upgrade the plugin versions as well:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-rc01'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}
```

Make sure all your dependencies are using the most recent stable version.

You should also update your Kotlin plugin version:

211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40

If you don't know where to set this, click on:

`Android Studio > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Kotlin`

Finally, I strongly recommend that you use Java 11 instead of 8 and set your app's build.gradle to this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

apply from: 'codeinc.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mydomain.myapp.blablahblah"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionName "1.0.0"
        
        versionCode 1
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.6.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: While good suggestions, updating everything did not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: "Very old"?! At the time of your writing, Compose 1.0.5 (used by the asker) was barely 3 months old.

Answer (score 2):

Add to `build.gradle.kts`

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = Depends.kotlin
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = Depends.compose
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. `buildFeatures { compose = true }` and `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` were also set. Since I had an old configuration of the project the solution was in adding the following code to the `root/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

However, I was also using `buildSrc` and it became a nightmare to migrate from this approach to the [plugins](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/how-to-use-composite-builds-as-a-replacement-of-buildsrc-in-gradle-64ff99344b58). Keep calm and several days.

After everything was migrated I was able to launch the code without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in a KMP Project , then I resolve this problem after I add compose plugin。

at first, add compose plugin in settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.4.3"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }
}
```

then use it in your module's build.gradle

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}
```

at last , sync and run your app

Answer (score 0):

For integration of composeView you must have to add below dependency;
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'

Also, don't forget supporting version of kotlin with compose version.

If you are using compose version as 1.1.1 you have to use kotlin version